# Expect-like tool for windows

Tags: command-line, batch-file, expect

I am searching for a tool that behaves similarly to Unix's [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) tool (or at least, its main function).

I want to automate command-line interactive programs with it.

EDIT:
I am preferring single executables or small apps without big multi megabyte depencies.

Ty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at ActiveState's [Tcl distribution](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/) which has a port of [Expect for Windows](http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.5/expect4win/welcome.html).

Comment: Check the new licensing model for 2021 which may mean you need a license.

Answer (score 7):

Late answer: Expect.exe, compiled with Go, running Lua-scripts. Fairly new, but does exactly what it is supposed to do. See https://github.com/zetamatta/expect/

Check the closed issues as well.

Comment: Absolutely perfect. It had a little bug when I first tried it, but the dev fixed it just a few hours after I opened the issue ❤

Answer (score 1):

I guess [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) is what you need.

Comment: AutoIt/AutoHotKey can't expect things from console apps.
They are GUI automation tools. Plus AutoIt is slow as hell.

Answer (score 0):

I your familiar with *expect*, then why not install Cygwin and run it that way?

Comment: because i need to install cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pexpect](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect), written in Python.

Comment: Thanks, updated the URL for pexpect and removed the google code link.

Comment: Sadly, pexpect only runs on *nix (and probably Cygwin): http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#requirements This question is about Windows.

Comment: It seems it does run on Windows as of version 4.0, with some caveats.