# Automatically provide the root user password to "su" executed using Plink from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, ssh, putty, plink

I'm having a difficult time getting the input from the root password line to auto plug in just like the `ssh` password does. So far I have this, then it crashes. I'm trying to get the batch file to input the ip, ssh password, then give `su` access then auto input the root pass. Anything would help thanks!

```
color b
cls
echo What is the IP for the unit?:
set /p IP= :

echo What is the SSH Password for this unit?:
set /p Passw0rd= :

echo What is the Root Password for this unit?:
set /p R0ot= :

plink.exe -t -ssh user@%IP% -pw %Passw0rd% -m commands.txt 

exit/b
```

What's in `command.txt`:

```
su
```

Answer (score 2):

First a word of warning: Automating `su`, particularly `su` with a password, is usually a bad idea: [Allowing automatic command execution as root on Linux using SSH](https://superuser.com/q/1481318/213663).

The `su` is designed to resist the automation.

---

Anyway, the `su` expects the password on its input. The `plink` forwards its input to the remote command input.

So all you need to do is to pass your variable as an input to the `plink` (see [How to pass user input automatically using plink.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34477728/850848)):

```
echo %R0ot%| plink -t -ssh user@%IP% -pw %Passw0rd% -m command.txt
```

You can also execute the `su` directly on the `plink` commandline, avoid the need for `command.txt`:

```
echo %R0ot%| plink -t -ssh user@%IP% -pw %Passw0rd% su
```

The `-t` is needed `su` will typically refuse to run without terminal emulation. On the other hand, `-t` can cause you troubles. For example, with `-t` you might have to feed the password to `plink` only at the moment `su` prompts for it. So you may need a [`expect`-linke tool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1276561/850848). Or use a hackish solution, like delaying the input, see [Wait between sending login and commands to serial port using Plink](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55851109/850848).

---

Another related question, showing slightly different approaches:
[Execute sudo command on Linux from plink.exe on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20248009/850848)